# Eigenvalues of 5x5 matrix given equation involving matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been given the matrix $A$ and we are told it is a $5\times 5$  matrix s.t. $A^4=A^2\neq A$. I want to find the eigenvalues so I tried $A^2(A-I)(A+I)=0$ so the eigenvalues are $0, 1, -1$ but I don't think this is right, I think I have missed some. The whole question is wanting to find the possible characteristic and minimal polynomials of $A$ hence my want to find the e-values. Am I doing it right? I have seen this sort of problem before where you have a matrix equal to some power of itself or similar and I can never do them, any hints on how to do this or similar problems would be useful, thank you!

Comment: Those are definitely the only possible eigenvalues.  Say $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.  Then $A^2v=\lambda^2v$ and $A^4v = \lambda^4v$.  Since $A^2=A^4$, we must have $\lambda^2v=\lambda^4v$.  Since $v$ is non-zero, that means $\lambda^2=\lambda^4$.  The roots of that equation are, as you found, 1, -1, and 0.  So far, this doesn't say that any of these *definitely are* eigenvalues; on the other hand, we also haven't used $A\ne A^2$, but I don't see that that really gives us enough information to be sure exactly what the eigenvalues are.